# How can a root ViewController push multiple ViewControllers on the stack?

Tags: ios, swift

When my TabBarViewController gets a notification, I want it to perform a push segue to UserViewController.

Every time it gets a notification, I want it to push another one onto the stack.

```
TabBarVC -> UserVC -> UserVC -> UserVC
```

The UserVC won't be calling any segues.

Right now, when I get a notification, I perform a push segue.

```
func newUserIncoming(notification:NSNotification){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(SEGUES.TabBarToUserVC, sender: self)
}
```

Comment: And what's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: @Wain every time my TabBarVC calls performSegue, it deinits the first  UserVC

Comment: If you have navigation Controller in your hierarchy than you can write a method in which you can create a new instance of UserVC and push it in your navigation Controller.

Comment: Show the code you're using. Explain how your segues are configured and how you're testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `newUserIncoming` function, instead of performing that segue, you'll need to create a new instance of UserVC and push that onto the stack like this:

```
func newUserIncoming(notification:NSNotification){
    let userVC = UserVC()
    // perform any setup code for userVC you may need to do
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(userVC, animated: true)
}
```

This way you'll keep all of the other UserVCs on the stack, below the newest one being pushed on.

Comment: Thanks. Can the final UserVC perform an unwindToRoot segue to go back to the root?